# Detect Man In The Middle From An Application

Tags: security, fiddler, man-in-the-middle

I did an interesting experiment today.

I opened Amazon.com in my browser, logged in, brought up Fiddler, and tried to add a brand new credit card.

I typed in my credit card number, expiration, and card holder name.  When I submitted the request I didn't see any POST to Amazon in Fiddler.  The UI said there was a problem submitting my information, and that I should try again.

I repeated it and got the identical response.

I shut down Fiddler and hit submit.  My information was accepted *instantly*.

I'd like to know how Amazon accomplished this feat.  Is it common knowledge?  Is there an HTTP header involving certificates that makes it easy?

Comment: Did you got your error message from the browser or from Amazon?

Comment: The error message appeared in the Amazon app in the browser.  It wasn't a popup; it looked like a validation message you'd expect from a web app if you typed bad values into a text box.

Comment: @Pillar, I added the java tag b/c I'm interested in adding this to a Java app.  I agree that it's not pertinent to the question.

Comment: there are some possible solutions to preventing man-in-the-middle attacks as you attempted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808930/what-is-point-of-ssl-if-fiddler-2-can-decrypt-all-calls-over-https apparently Client-side certification for SSL authentication is a thing? Also did you enable ssl traffic in the settings for fiddler?

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give those a look.  Yes, SSL traffic was enabled in Fiddler.

Comment: You should consider asking this same question (or having it migrated to) [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Good suggestion, @esqew.  How to migrate?

Comment: @duffymo You can flag your question and explain to the moderators in the box provided that you feel it might be better suited for Security.SE.

Comment: Thanks so much; greatly appreciated.  Sincerely....

Answer (score 1):

I think it is certificate pinning or something like it. Server certificate is pinned in application, so app accept only it, not any other certs even they are valid.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, I'll dig into that.

Comment: It's unlikely to be HTTPS key pinning. Per a check on securityheaders.io, Amazon [doesn't actually send that header at all](https://securityheaders.io/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com).

Comment: You are right. What else it can be?

Comment: All things aside, I'm not sure how HPKP would really affect this; that header's mostly for the server to resist impersonation by other servers, not for the client to resist impersonation by other clients.